# Add a new view in app after clicking on notification in android?

Tags: android, view, notifications, android-alertdialog

I am actually working with `notifications` in Android.

To do my application test, I follow [the guide on android.developer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) .

I create my notification, it works well. When I click on it, it removes the notification from the notification tab and after I go to my Activity.

**Here is the code I use to do that :**

```
    public void createSimpleNotification() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder  mNotifBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this.getApplicationContext())
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notif).setContentTitle("Simple notif").setContentText("Welcome on our app, click here");

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    TaskStackBuilder mStackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this.getApplicationContext());
    mStackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    mStackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = mStackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    mNotifBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    NotificationManager mNotifManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotifManager.notify(0, mNotifBuilder.build());
}
```

I only have my `MainActivity` and a `Button`. When I click on the button, the notification appears and I click on notification, i come back to my MainActivity.

**Here is my problem :**

I want to update my `MainActivity UI` after clicking on the notification. After clicking on notification, I need to create a `Dialog` who shows the text of the notification.

How can I modify my `Activity` and add new `View` after clicking on a notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a view that is already there. So you create it in your activity, and set it's Visibility to `FALSE`.

Now if you want it to appear, put your notification text in it and set Visibility to `TRUE`. This should serve your request ;)

Comment: I aggree with you but how I access my View on onClick on the notification ?

Comment: You create your View in your Activity. Just make it a static class variable. then you can access it via `ActivityWithView.myNotificationView` for example

Comment: Yes I understand what you say but how I know if the notification has been clicked ?

Comment: `After clicking on notification, I need to create a Dialog` I assume that there is a Button or something else. Just add an onClickListener

Comment: Yes, there is a Button, when I click on it the notification appears in notification tab. But if I had my View after the onClickListener of the Button, it will display directly the View. I will not have the time to click on the notification. The click on the notification must change the Activity view.

Comment: What you need for this is a PendingIntent: [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html). Here is an example on how to use it with notifications: -[link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNotifications/article.html#pendingintent)

Comment: I have only one Activity. I can't create an other one

Comment: This will help you: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13822509/android-call-method-on-notification-click)

Comment: I will try with links you shared. I come back if it doesn't work and accept the answer if it works.

Comment: Thank you for your help and your time ! It works with the `onNewIntent` method and your links.

Answer (score 0):

you can add put an Extra to your result Intent

such as:

`resultIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME, EXTRA_VALUE);`

then handle it in your MainActivity onNewIntent

```
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (intent.hasExtra(EXTRA_NAME)) {
            // do your things here
        }
    }
```